# Input focus causes font blurring / antialiasing in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

It seems that there is some strange anti aliasing behavior in Chrome when there are inputs present. When focusing inside an input the font aliasing seems to change. Depending on the color of the font the change might be more pronounced. Changing the -webkit-font-aliasing or whatever that property is does not seem to change anything.

Unfocused:

[image]

Focused:

[image]

The bug appears not only with the tailwind reset which is where the first image examples were from but also in vanilla CSS. The link to the [first example is here](https://play.tailwindcss.com/QIjS6tvgeB).

Unfocusd:

[image]

Focused:

[image]

```html
<input type='text' />
<p>Something went wrong</p>
```

```css
body {
  background: #000;
  color: #ccc;
}
```

The link to the [second example on jsfiddle is here](https://jsfiddle.net/bad2ycfz/)

Is there a way to fix this blurring / remove it?

Chrome: Version 111.0.5563.65 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Chromium bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1423434

Answer (score 1):

Chromium bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1423434

Try using `position: relative` (or other `position` that is not `static`) for `<input/>` as a workaround.

Tailwind sample: https://play.tailwindcss.com/4L5Q9u3qkK

Comment: I tried that but it just makes it so that the text is **always** in the "unaliased" - or the worse of the two states.

Comment: @TheTruth Current problems with subpixel antialiasing have been around for about a year, I think. On some sites partially (stackoverflow sidebars, topbar, youtube video titles in all columns expect first, etc.), on some completely (twitter at least) there is no subpixel anti-aliasing.

Comment: were they not around before and if not how come? Why the sudden appearance?

Comment: @TheTruth it's some kind of layers/painting bug(s), and it was not fixed for at least 11 months. I don't know when it appeared exactly, I was just looking for information about subpixex antialiasing problems at https://bugs.chromium.org/